# Implement branchless binary search

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, search

## Challenge

Implement binary search on a list of length 256 with no branches.

## Specification

- Input an integer `X` and a strictly increasing list of integers
- Output is the greatest element of the list that is less than or equal to `X`
- The output will always exist
- List will always have exactly 256 elements and be strictly increasing
- The algorithm must be a binary search on the list

## Example code (with branches)

Without branches, these examples would be valid entries.

First a functional example (actually valid Haskell code):

```
b value list = b' 0 7
  where
    b' pos bitpos | bitpos < 0                          = list !! pos
                  | (list !! (pos + 2^bitpos)) <  value = b' (pos + 2^bitpos) (bitpos - 1)
                  | (list !! (pos + 2^bitpos)) == value = list !! (pos + 2^bitpos)
                  | otherwise                           = b' pos (bitpos - 1)
```

Now a pseudocode iterative example:

```
b(value, list):
  pos = 0
  bitpos = 7
  while bitpos >= 0:
    if list[pos + 2^bitpos] < value
       pos    += 2^bitpos
    elseif list[pos + 2^bitpos] == value
      return list[pos + 2^bitpos]
    bitpos -= 1
  return list[pos]
```

## Rules

- Branches include: `if/then`, `switch`, `case`, `for`, `while`, `?:`, guards, and all other branches
- Instead of a list, you may use a list-like object, so space separated string, vector, etc.
- Entry may be a function or full program
- If your language has a function that solves this challenge, it is not allowed
- Score is in bytes, lowest score wins!

## Example Input/Output (abbreviated)

```
Input:  50, [..21,34,55,89,144..]
Output: 34

Input:  15, [..2,3,15,25,34,35..]
Output: 15

Input:  144, [..37,50,65,82,101,122,145..]
Output: 122
```

Comment: Maybe separating the specifications from the rules would make it clearer for those who closed it?

Comment: @user81655 Good suggestion. I also added examples and the algorithm in two forms. Do you think I should add a worked example?

Comment: Personally I think it's very clear as it is now. The test cases really help.

Comment: @user81655 Great, now I just have to wait

Comment: Might as well just leave this here for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## C, 75 bytes

Here's the code:

```
#define g p+=(x>=p[i/=2])*i
b(x,p,i)int*p;{i=256;g;g;g;g;g;g;g;g;return*p;}
```

Less golfed:

```
int bin_search(int x, int * p){
    int i = 256;
    i = i / 2;
    p += (p[i] <= x) * i;
    \\ above two lines repeated 8 times
    return *p;
}
```

Comment: Noncompeting why?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy I'll edit, I just accepted my own answer because it didn't look like anyone else was going to answer. If you want to post an answer, I'll reopen.